# Reload the page when the page previously opened getting closed

Tags: jquery, events, onfocus

My page "a" is launching a page "b" from a link (allow me to edit the informations of the "a" page)

```
<a href="b" target="_blank">link</a>
```

After saving in the "b" page i do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       window.close();
    })
</script>
```

So my browser get back to the "a" page.
I would like to know if there is a possibility to detect this event (something like OnNavClosing or OnFocusBack) so i can reload the "a" page with updated informations ? (Without changing the process of how i edit informations ^^)
I don't really like the idea of making a "Onfocus" event, because i think it will reload too many time and not only when i came back to this page.

Cheer.

Comment: Try opening it with `window.open...` and then closing it in page **b** with `window.opener.location.reload()` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply call `window.opener.location.reload()` when you close your window:

```
$(function() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: Quick, efficient, thanks you ! (I just have to replace my <a href="b" target="_blank">link</a>" to <a onclick="window.open('b');" >link</a>) so it can work, but that's not a big deal)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @putvande's idea is actually great. You can use `window.opener` property to fire an event at the original window to let it know what's going on, e.g. `$(window.opener).trigger("updatePage", [arguments/variables]);`

---

One problem you are going to encounter is that different tabs or windows all excute in their own context, thus preventing you from directly affecting one script from another (even if it is a different instantiation of the same script).

I think the easiest way to work around this (although this is off the top of my head and I haven't tested it) is to add a variable to your localstorage (for example `shouldUpdatePage`). You can then, in your script, attach an event handler to the change event for the localstorage [explanation of HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

**But even then I don't think that will work,** because I think that the event will only be called on the `window` which actually initiated the change to the localStorage. Of course, you could still check the variable manually using `setInterval()`, and clearing that interval-ed check when you have closed the editing window.

But, as you are obviously already expecting ("Without changing the process of how i edit informations ^^"), handling your edits in a new window is just not a very neat or user-friendly way to handle that. (For example, doing it in the same window/tab allows you to make use of all kinds of `location` and history variables. Going back one page? No problem: `history.go(-1);`)